# Querying Elasticsearch with PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm having a little trouble translating some of the queries I use for elasticsearch into PHP readable queries.

For example this simple query works:

```
$query = $elastic->search([
body' => [
    'query' => [
        'match' => [
            'myfield' => 'mymatchingresult'
        ]
    ]
]
]);
```

But what I'm trying to get to work follow below. There isn't an error, it just doesn't run. I must not be understanding the structure. The same query if placed in something like google extension sense seems to work. (With the php '=>' converted to ':' etc.)

```
$query = $elastic->search([
'body' => [
    'query' => [
        'filtered' => [
            'query' => [
                'query_string' => [
                    'query' => '*',
                    'analyze_wildcard' => 'true'
                ]
            ],
            'filter' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'must' => [ 
                        'query' => [
                            'query_string' => [
                                'analyze_wildcard' => 'true',
                                'query' => 'cn:name'
                            ]
                        ],
                        'range' => [
                            '@timestamp' => [
                                'from' => '2012-05-01',
                                'to' => '2016-05-01'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
]);
```

Thank you for the help!
-John

Comment: Can you try this query in its cURL form directly to your ES server? Debugging php+ES can be a pain. My experience and recommendation is to try first your query via curl. When you are sure it works then try the php equivalent. Specially if your falling into silent and weird behaviors. Try that and paste any output error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the constraints in your `bool/must` filter must be enclosed in square brackets, i.e. `bool/must` should be a pure array, not an associative array.

Like this:

```
$query = $elastic->search([
'body' => [
    'query' => [
        'filtered' => [
            'query' => [
                'query_string' => [
                    'query' => '*',
                    'analyze_wildcard' => 'true'
                ]
            ],
            'filter' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'must' => [ 
                      [
                        'query' => [
                            'query_string' => [
                                'analyze_wildcard' => 'true',
                                'query' => 'cn:name'
                            ]
                        ]
                      ],
                      [
                        'range' => [
                            '@timestamp' => [
                                'from' => '2012-05-01',
                                'to' => '2016-05-01'
                            ]
                        ]
                      ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
]);
```